# What causes repeating addresses in Tracert output and really slow internet access

Tags: networking, routing, traceroute

```
ISP: Comcast
Router: Netgear N 600
OS: Windows 10 (2 different machines: HP Zbook G3 and Toshiba Ultrabook) and iPad (old series 3 IOS 9) iPhone 6 (IOS 10)
```

Problem: The Toshiba machine frequently gets extremely bad Internet performance (to the point of being unusable). At other times it is fine.  All other devices work fine without issues.

I have looked at All the normal villains (CPU, network connection speed etc etc. ), they all seem fine.  I have looked at the IPv4 configs for both machines and they seem similar, I have flushed the DNS cache and that does not seem to make any difference. MTU sizes on both machines are the same.  `IPCONFIG RELEASE/RENEW` makes no difference either.

The only odd thing I can see is that when I run tracert to www.Google.com from the slow machine, I get the output shown below (trace#1) but from the other Windows machine (ZBook), which is working normally, I get a more normal Tracert display shown below (trace#2) (note: tracert from the the iPad gives the same "normal" response). Both tracerts were done at exactly the same time. Other sites beside Google.com have the same problem - I used Google just as an illustration.

When I access "local network" resources on the Local LAN from the Toshiba, everything works fine and data moves very well.  I have copied large files, viewed videos etc without any problem, leading me to believe that something is happening on the other side of the router but why would one machine be so bad and the other fine good?

I have reinstalled network driver but there is no change to my problem.

******* Trace #1 From Toshiba (Bad) **********

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert www.google.com

Tracing route to www.google.com [216.58.219.228] over a maximum of 30 hops:

1 2 ms <1 ms <1 ms RS [192.168.1.1]
2 9 ms 9 ms 8 ms 96.120.72.69
3 * 483 ms * xe-5-0-0-sur01.portmurry.nj.panjde.comcast.net [68.85.116.213]
4 10 ms 10 ms 11 ms 162-151-210-177-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net [162.151.210.177]
5 12 ms 13 ms 13 ms be-33659-cr02.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.90.21]
6 15 ms 11 ms 10 ms hu-0-10-0-7-pe01.111eighthave.ny.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.87.110]
7 2615 ms * * as27589-2.miami.fl.ibone.comcast.net [75.149.228.186]
8 1670 ms * * 216.239.62.125
9 * 2521 ms * 64.233.174.117
10 875 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
11 1759 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
12 1737 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
13 1614 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
14 1497 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
15 1353 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
16 1738 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
17 1597 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
18 1499 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
19 1384 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
20 1806 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
21 1686 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
22 1575 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
23 1463 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
24 1835 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
25 1712 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
26 1610 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
27 1486 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
28 1876 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
29 1764 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]
30 1662 ms * * lga25s41-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.219.228]

Trace complete.
```

********** Trace #2 From HP (Good) **************

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert www.google.com

Tracing route to www.google.com [172.217.4.68] over a maximum of 30 hops:

1 <1 ms <1 ms <1 ms RS [192.168.1.1]
2 9 ms 13 ms 8 ms 96.120.72.69
3 313 ms 10 ms * xe-5-0-0-sur01.portmurry.nj.panjde.comcast.net [68.85.116.213]
4 13 ms 11 ms 11 ms 162-151-210-177-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net [162.151.210.177]
5 14 ms 14 ms 13 ms be-33659-cr02.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.90.21]
6 16 ms 13 ms 13 ms hu-0-13-0-0-pe03.111eighthave.ny.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.85.182]
7 2219 ms 11 ms 12 ms as15169-2-c.111eighthave.ny.ibone.comcast.net [23.30.206.126]
8 12 ms 13 ms 12 ms 216.239.50.108
9 12 ms 12 ms 13 ms 209.85.240.113
10 16 ms 12 ms 12 ms lga15s47-in-f4.1e100.net [172.217.4.68]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but that last hop is the Google server. In your Toshiba's tracert it seems to be either trying to hop to that same server more than once, or bouncing off other servers inside Google's network, which seems weird.

Comment: Somehow you are getting a different IP addresses for www.google.com on each machine. How is your DNS set up on each machine? What DNS servers are you using?

Comment: @DavidPostill : Both are set to use the DNS server on the router (192.168.1.1).  I tried changing it to explicitly use Google's DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 but that didn't change things. I tried rebooting the router etc. nothing seems to change the problem...then just as mysteriously the problem goes away for an hour or two.....

Comment: @ IronWilliamCash:  Yep - it is odd.  I see the same sort of thing happening at other web sites too so I doubt that it is actually Google related.  I can't seem to find anything  on the Web that talks to this diirectly.

Comment: Do your `tracert` by IP instead of host name to rule out DNS.

Comment: @Stephen Next time it happens it would be interesting to see the output of `nslookup www.google.com` on both machines. Google I believe uses a round robin DNS to load balance but in my case all the addresses are `87.237.19.xx` not very different addresses as in your case. To me it looks like a problem with the Comcast network (starting at hop 7, which is different in the 2 traceroutes).

Comment: Right now both machines are working normally and guess what Tracert are the same using the same explicit ip address... Unfortunately the comment section will not let me copy in the entire trace but it gets there in 10 hops without any hop taking longer than 15 ms 
Trace complete.

Comment: I would agree that it looks like a Comcast networking issue, however it only ever impacts the one machine.  Very puzzled by this.  I have been working on this on and off for a couple of weeks but since it is intermittent it is difficult to diagnose.

Comment: @DavidPostill When it goes flaky I'll do nslookup on Google.com... However as I said it is not just Google ... I had the same sort of result with GHBass.com  and many other web sites... even web.mail.Comcast.net.

Comment: I have to go out in a few mins so any reply I make will be probably late tonight or tomorrow (Saturday)